# django How to create a model value without setting a field's value?

Tags: python, django

In the table field, x is auto-created by the database

//postgres

```sql
create table t(
    id serial primary key,
    x integer default nextval("x-auto-add")
)
```

I had created a serial named 'x-auto-add' and when I exec

```
insert into t(id) values(1)
```

the result is right, the x field is auto-add by 1.

However, when I use restful API by Django

```
x = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

x = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True)
```

when I post

```
{"id":4}
```

table t add a record 4,null

Comment: sorry, you question does not make sense. What do you want to achieve? Why you are using sql query instead of django ORM to create tables?

Comment: @ruddra model is banner, to achieve exchange the position of two banners,using field `show_index` to control.this field is auto-create when a banner is created and auto-add by 1 through the database serial

Comment: @ruddra the table is shared by some members ,I don't generate it .